# How to count the records per half hour from a period (datetimefrom and datetimeto) field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table which looks like you can see below:

```
 Id   Date        ScheduledTimeFrom     ScheduledTimeTo      ActualTimeFrom       ActualTimeTo
 1   2013-01-01   1899-12-30 07:00:00   1899-12-30 18:00:00  1899-12-30 07:23:00  1899-12-30 17:15:00
```

I need to calculate per half hour how many records exists, the output should be like:

```
 Time      Actual Count:
 7:00      4
 7:30      4
 8:00      4
 8:30      4
 9:00      4
 9:30      5
 10:00     5
 10:30     6
 11:00     7
 11:30     8
 12:00     8
 12:30     8
 13:00     8
 13:30     8
 14:00     8
 14:30     8
 15:00     7
 15:30     7
 16:00     7
 16:30     6
 17:00     5
 17:30     4
 18:00     4
```

I already tried to make a helper table which should hold the times per halfhour. I have joined this helpertable with the table that contains the data and after that I tried to use a group by function but it was not working.

My query was like:

```
Create table period (timefrom datetime, timeto datetime)
insert into period
select '1899-12-30 07:00:00.000', '1899-12-30 07:30:00.000'
Union all
select '1899-12-30 07:30:00.000', '1899-12-30 08:00:00.000'


select * 
from period p left join table1 t on t.ActualTimeFrom < p.timeto and t.ActualTimeTo  >=p.timefrom

Grouping this give me no desired result....
```

Anyone an idea how to come to the result?

P.s. I am using sql server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

After snooping around and testing it on my side, looks like this date function could be the answer:

```
DATEADD(mi,DATEDIFF(mi,0,YOUR_DATE_COLUMN)/30*30,0)
```

Comment: Should I use this line in the group by section? Please make your answer concrete...

Comment: Use it in both your SELECT and your GROUP BY, specify your date range in your WHERE clause. e.g. WHERE your_date_column > your_start_date AND your_date_column < your_end_date.